# Transforming a string into a list of pairs comprising the character from each run together with its number of repetitions

Tags: haskell

So I am required to convert a list of strings to a [(Char,Int)]. So for example, `["xxxxx","yyy"]` to `[('x',5), ('y',3)]` . I am able to get the `('x',5)` part without any issues but I am not sure how to move on to the next element of the list. Here is my code so far. Any pointers will be greatly appricated.

```
[(x,y) | let x = head(head(reap xs)), let y =  length(head(reap xs)))]
```

p.s : `reap` is a function that turns a string into a list of repeated characters. For example `"aaaabbbbccc"` -> `["aaaa","bbbb","bbb"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest breaking this into smaller parts. First define a function that takes a single `String` and returns a tuple `(Char, Int)`. Then once you have this function , you can use `map` to apply it to each `String` in a list.

Comment: [(x,y) | let x = head(head(reap xs)), let y = length(head(reap xs)))]

^     That is the function that takes a single String and return a tuple (Char, Int)

Comment: @BraxWong `[(x,y) | let x = head(head(reap xs)), let y = length(head(reap xs)))] ` is a list comprehension, not a function. It looks like your list comprehension creates a list of `(Char, Int)`. My suggestion is to write a function that creates a single `(Char, Int)` instead of trying to do the entire list all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fmap` function which applies a function over or any item in the list.
The function `charRepetitions` accepts a list and uses the `charRepetition` function to transform an item.

```
main = do
  _ <- print $ charRepetitions ["xxxxx","yyy"] 
  return ()

charRepetitions :: [String] -> [(Char, Int)]
charRepetitions xs = fmap charRepition xs

charRepetition :: String -> (Char, Int)
charRepetition s = (head s , length s)
```